# CI 3.1.8 set_cookie() doesn't work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I know there are so many question about this `set_cookie()` CI, but I can't found the answer, the cookie doesn't showing in Google Cookies Data menu.

I know how to read it, but it doesn't showing at all in the browser cookies data.

in `ControllerFile.php`

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$cookie = array(
    'name'      => 'pre',
    'value'     => $token,
    'expire'    => 86400 * 7,
);
$this->input->set_cookie(
    $cookie['name'], $cookie['value'], $cookie['expire']
);
```

The setting in `config.php`

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'e_';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.localhost';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/project.com/catch/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

This website Project is under *project.com* folder, this is what it looks like

```
htdocs/
---- project.com/
-------- catch/
------------ *CI files*
--------- *files*
--------- *files*
---- anotherproject.com/
---- anotherproject.com/
---- anotherproject.com/
```

But there are no cookie data for `[::1]` nor `.localhost`, why does this happening?

I already tried to googled it but can't found the solution, I already tried with

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

But it doesn't work either.

Adding `log file`

```
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Helper loaded: file_helper
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Email Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Session: "sess_save_path" is empty; using "session.save_path" value from php.ini.
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Model "User_model" initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Model "Cookie_model" initialized
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Helper loaded: cookie_helper
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Language file loaded: language/english/form_validation_lang.php
INFO - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2018-05-18 08:28:37 --> Total execution time: 0.1759
```

As you can see, in the log file there are no error message at all

My Google chrome setting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Try Using Array Method (Alternative), an associative array is passed to `set_cookie`:*

**Replace it**

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'      => 'pre',
    'value'     => $token,
    'expire'    => 86400 * 7,
);
$this->input->set_cookie(
    $cookie['name'], $cookie['value'], $cookie['expire']
);
```

**With this :**

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'      => 'pre',
    'value'     => $token,
    'expire'    => 86400 * 7,
    /* no need to set domain if localhost */
    'domain' => '.localhost',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => 'e_',
    'secure' => FALSE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

To check your cookies

```
print_r($this->input->cookie());
```

Reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: Ahhh I see, why it doesn't set it's because I use the domain and put path value, but if I just leave the `domain` blank and put **/** in `path` it'll be OK! Thanks!